# Block hasura from sharing request information in remote schema errors

Tags: hasura

When hasura has a remote schema error (such as a timeout) it shares all the request details to the client calling it including any internal forwarded header files which can include shared secrets.

Is there a way to prevent it from doing this?

Comment: might you need to set `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_INTERNAL_ERRORS` to `false`?  it sounds like that solved a similar problem (for actions, not remote schema) in this github issue: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/8062#issuecomment-1018159970.

docs: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/deployment/graphql-engine-flags/reference/#command-flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has to do with the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE` configuration in the docker file, setting this to 'false' or not at all fixes the issue and masks the error.